# Proving a function $f(t,x)$ is Lipschitz Continous with respect to the second variable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am given the following Cauchy Problem, $$x'=e^{-t^2}x+\text{sin}^{2}(tx)$$ $$x(1)=0$$ where $(t,x)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

I am asked to prove that it has only one solution $\varphi$ defined in $\mathbb{R}$ and also, to find it.

I tried to prove that $f(t,x)=e^{-t^2}x+\text{sin}^{2}(tx)$ satisfies all the hypotheses in the [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) which garantees existence an uniqueness of solutions.

My questions,

1. First of all I don't really know if $f$ satisfies the hypotheses (that's part of the reason I asked this question).
2. Second, is there another way to prove existence and uniqueness without using [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem), I heard about Peano and also decreasing $f$, but I have no idea what they are.

My attempt in proving that the Cauchy Problem satisfied the hypotheses.

> First of all, the hypotheses for the theorem are for $f(t,x)=e^{-t^2}x+\text{sin}^{2}(tx)$ to be continous as well as Lipschitz-continous with respect to the second variable $x$. $$$$ Since exponentials and trigonometric functions are continous, as well as the product and sum of them, the first part should be done (right?). Secondly I have to see if $f$ has the property of being Lipschitz-continous. $$|f(t,x)-f(t,y)|=|e^{-t^2}x+\text{sin}^{2}(tx)-e^{-t^2}y+\text{sin}^{2}(ty)|=|e^{-t^2}(x-y)+\text{sin}^{2}(tx)-\text{sin}^{2}(ty)|=$$ $$|e^{-t^2}(x-y)+2t\text{sin}(t\zeta)\text{cos}(t\zeta)(x-y)|\leq|e^{-t^2}|+|2t\text{sin}(t\zeta)\text{cos}(t\zeta)||x-y|\leq$$ $$(3+2|a|)|x-y|$$
> where $(t,x)\in[1-a,1+a]\times[-b,b]=:I_a(1)\times D_b(0)=:\Omega$. $$$$ So by [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem), would have proven that there exists a unique solution (right?). $$$$The theorem not only states that there is a unique solution, but it also gives an interval $I$ from the domain of $\varphi$. Let $M:=\text{max}\{||f(t,x)||:(t,x)\in\Omega\}$, then by [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) there exists a unique solution defined on $I_{\text{min}(a,b/M)}(1)$. Choosing $a$ small enough we get $I=\mathbb{R}$. Is that right? $$$$ Finally, for the solution. It is obvious that the only solution is $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$, where $\varphi(t)=0$.

I would like to know if my arguments were given correctly. Any help would be really much apreciated.

Comment: It is often easier to argue that the function is $C^1$, the same way you argued continuity. Then local Lipschitz follows, which is sufficient here as you can directly give the maximal IVP solution.